# F# "exit early" computation expression?

Tags: f#, computation-expression

In attempting to learn more about how computation expressions work, I'm attempting to code a builder that skips the remainder of the expression after evaluating the `then` block of an `if` statement, whereupon the workflow itself would evaluate to `true`.  The workflow should return `false` if none of the `if` statements evaluated to `true`.

For example:

```
let mutable x = 0

let result =
    earlyExit {
        if false then x <- 99
        if true then x <- 33
        if true then x <- 11
    }
```

Here, `result` should be `true`, and `x` should be `33`.

The closest I've gotten is:

```
type EarlyExitBuilder () =
    member this.Combine (a, b) = a || b ()
    member this.Delay fn = fn
    member this.Run fn = fn ()
    member this.Zero () = false
```

... which results in the workflow evaluating to `false`, and `x` to `11`.

Is this doable using the syntax in my example?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710700/f-computation-expression-for-nested-boolean-tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smallest change that would give you the behaviour that you are looking for is probably to add `return` to the computation - the `return` construct can return `true` and terminate the evaluation early:

```
let mutable x = 0

let result =
    earlyExit {
        if false then return x <- 99
        if true then return x <- 33
        if true then return x <- 11
    }
```

This evaluates to `true` and the value of `x` will be `33`. The computation builder is the same as yours, with additional `Return` member returning `true`:

```
type EarlyExitBuilder () =
    member this.Combine (a, b) = a || b ()
    member this.Delay fn = fn
    member this.Run fn = fn ()
    member this.Zero () = false
    member this.Return( () ) = true
```

As mentioned in one of the referenced answers, this is somewhat related to my [imperative computation builder](http://tomasp.net/blog/imperative-i-return.aspx) which lets you use imperative-style `return` and an [extended version with break and continue](http://tomasp.net/blog/imperative-ii-break.aspx/).

Comment: Excellent, thank you, Tomas!  You always come through for us budding F# enthusiasts.  :)

Nice to know that I was *that* close to realizing a solution.

Comment: @MiloDC It was a fun question :) computation expressions always hide some unexpected surprises (even for me!)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's any good way to do this using the syntax you're proposing; inside of a computation expression, something like

```
if c then e
```

is going to get compiled to something like

```
if c then 
    e
    builder.Zero() 
else 
    builder.Zero()
```

so there's no way for the context to differentiate which branch was taken.